# Can't logout on my site when using getLogoutUrl()

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I've got 2 tabs open in Firefox, one is my website and the other is Facebook. Without the app authorised I get a login link, I click this which I am then prompted to auth the app which I do so.

I've now got on screen the logout URL provided by getLogoutUrl() - when I click this it redirects back to my site which I am happy with however it is still classing me as logged in. If I refresh the other tab with Facebook on I am now logged out. It seems there's some hangover on the session??

```
<?php
require_once("fb/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '...';
$config['secret'] = '...';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id) {
    //Got an ID - Facebook says we're logged in
    try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "<img src=\"http://graph.facebook.com/".$user_profile['username']."/picture\"><a href=\"".$user_profile['link']."\">" . $user_profile['name']."</a>";
        $logout_url = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        echo "<a href=\"" . $logout_url . "\">Logout</a><br><br><br>";

    } 
    catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }   
} 
else {
    // Not logged in - give URL to login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to destroy the session.

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act'] == "logout") {
    $facebook->destroySession();
}


$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
if ($user) {

    try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user_profile);
    echo "</pre>";  
    $logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    //echo $logout;

    echo "<a href='test.php?act=logout'>Logout</a>";


} else {

    $login = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"email","display"=>"popup","redirect_uri"=>"http://domain.com/test.php"));

    echo "<a href='".$login."'>Login</a>";

}
```